# How to get more than 25 decimal places after division?

Tags: java, double, division, bigdecimal

I tried this,

```java
BigDecimal dividend = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(69);
BigDecimal result = dividend.divide(divisor, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
System.out.println(result.toPlainString().length());
System.out.println(result.toPlainString());
```

But I had only 19 decimals!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any `MathContext` you like. `MathContext.DECIMAL64` is simply `new MathContext(16, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`.

So instead you could do

```
BigDecimal result = dividend.divide(divisor, new MathContext(26, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  Set the scale with the divisor and a rounding mode of your choice.

```
BigDecimal dividend = BigDecimal.valueOf( 1 );
BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf( 69 );

BigDecimal result = dividend.divide(divisor,100,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(result.toPlainString().length());
System.out.println( result.toPlainString( ) );
```

prints

```
102
0.014492753623188405797101449275362318840579710144927536231884057971014492753623
1884057971014492753623
```

Answer (score 0):

`MathContext.DECIMAL64` represents a BigDecimal using 64 *bits*, not 64 decimal digits. See the description at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL64